# How can I discard all the changes, which I didn’t push, so I made the changes locally in a branch and just want pull the current branch from GitLab

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I worked on a branch in [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA). I have deleted code out of sight and now just want to fetch the entire branch again without my changes remaining. I have not pushed anything. How can I do this?

Comment: did you try `git stash`?

Comment: What is git stash? How can I make this on intelij?

Comment: you can run this command in intellij console.

Comment: you can find its docs here https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Comment: git-stash - Stash the changes in a dirty working directory away

Comment: But what means that? The changes are hidden, so still accessible?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what have you managed to do at this point.

1. If you have already committed your changes, you can just do (make sure to check out to the appropriate branch before) `git reset --hard <COMMIT_HASH>` and reset the `HEAD` to the commit in the remote. Then you can just `git pull` and you should be fine.
2. If you have not committed anything yet, you can just do `git reset --hard HEAD` (Again, checkout to the branch you need in advance) and this will discard any staged and unstaged changes you have made.

P.S: Just beware that this approaches will **discard your local changes entirely** (though there will be an option to restore them via `git reflog`, but its another topic)

Answer (score 0):

Just as @JAMSHAID mentioned in comment, you could use the Git Stash feature to save the change and restore it back later.

See here to know how to use the Git Stash in IDEA: *[Stash changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-on-several-features-simultaneously.html#stash)*

Also check the [Git Stash documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).